# My jQuery dialog doesn't resize correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code that creates a jQuery dialog. The problem is that when it opens the dialog is not large enough and a scroll bar appears. It would seem that the resize is not working:

```
 $.get(url + separator + 'content=1')
            .done(function (content) {
                dialogs[id] = $('<div class="modal-popup">' + content + '</div>')
                    .hide() // Hide the dialog for now so we prevent flicker
                    .appendTo(document.body)
                    .filter('div') // Filter for the div tag only, script tags could surface
                    .dialog({ // Create the jQuery UI dialog
                        title: link.data('dialog-title'),
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        height: 'auto',
                        width: link.data('dialog-width') || 400,
                        buttons: {
                            "Submit": function () {                       
                            $("#dialogForm").submit(); },
                            "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                        },
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').
                    find('button:contains("Submit")').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plus'} });
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').
                    find('button:contains("Cancel")').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-cancel'} });
                            $(":input[type='checkbox']").wijcheckbox();
                            $(":input[type='text'],:input[type='password'],textarea").wijtextbox();      
                        }
                    })
                    .find('form') // Attach logic on forms
                        .submit(formSubmitHandler)
                    .end();
            });
    };
```

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong. I included all the code so you could see everything connected with the dialog box.

Could this be connected with the setting of overlow: auto? This is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: When you use inspect element with your browsers dev tools . What css height rule do you get for the dialog ?

Comment: <div class="modal-popup ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 43.2667px; height: auto;" scrolltop="8" scrollleft="0">

Comment: have you got a live version of this somewhere we can have a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to update the width option of your dialog as follows?

```
width: link.data('dialog-width')?link.data('dialog-width'):400
```

I'm not sure that your syntax works as expected.